# Change text strings in formatted bibliographic entries

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, natbib, languages

[image: Bibliography]

Hello, I am using the bibliography and bibliography style packages, but as you can see in the image, Pages and Edition are appearing in English. How do I change to Portuguese?

Comment: Do pleease tell us *which* bibliography style you employ.

Comment: using in the bibliographic style is plain

Comment: How do you say "and", "page", "pages", and "edition" in Portuguese?

Comment: page = página ; pages = páginas ; edition = edição

Comment: Packages babel or polyglossia usually translate that words.

Comment: @SergioLlorente - `babel` and `polyglossia` will change sectioning headers such "References". However, they do *not* modify the innards of the `plain` bibliography style file.

Comment: @Mico Ok. Therefore, one solution would be use biblatex?

Answer (score 2):

First, I would like to recommend that you employ (and modify) the `plainnat` rather than the `plain` bib style. `plainnat` is a re-implementation of the decades-old `plain` style that has been augmented to recognize field names such as `url`, `isbn`, `issn`, `doi`, and `eid`. The `plainnat` bib style is also capable of producing both authoryear-style *and* numeric-style citation call-outs; all you need to do is switch between `\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}` and `\usepackage[numbers,square]{natbib}`.

Second, here's how you might could go about assuring that the formatted bibliographic entries use Portuguese rather than English words.

- Find the file `plainnat.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `plainnat-pt.bst`.
- Open the file `plainnat-pt.bst` in a text editor. The program you use to edit your tex files will do fine.
- In the bst file, change all 3 instances of `" and "` to `" e "`, both instances of `"page"` to `"página"`, both instances of `"pages"` to `"páginas"`, and all 4 instances of `" edition"` to `" edição"`.
- Save the file `plainnat-pt.bst` either in the directory that houses your main tex file(s) or in a directory that's searched by BibTeX. If you choose the latter option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution suitably.
- In your main tex file, change `\bibliographstyle{plain}` to `\bibliographystyle{plainnat-pt}`, be sure to load `natbib` with the required options, and perform a full recompile cycle: LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more.

Happy BibTeXing!